# Plot non continuous data with lines using python matplotlib

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

I have a need to plot data with matplotlib that is a series, but has some values missing, so it's not entirely continuous. Currently the data is in the form of simple lists, with one value for each "N" value shown, from 15 to 40, so there is a list of those values, passed as the x information to the plotting command. The data is passed as a list for the y information, and currently possesses either a number of numpy.nan, for places where there is no data for this set.

What I need to do is plot it as shown, except that I need the missing datapoints to be ignored and the lines to connect between the next data points, for instance the red circle at x=20 should connect to the red circle at x=35, and the two markers are being plotted by the same plot command.

[image: Sample plot]

This code needs to plot various data sets, where some will have no data at 15, but it needs to be shown that there is no data, i.e. the axes remain the same for clarity and series are connected to show trends.

sample data for the red circle data:

```
[numpy.nan, 6.3, numpy.nan, numpy.nan, 8.4, numpy.nan]
```

sample data for the green circle data:

```
[numpy.nan, 4.1, 4.3, numpy.nan, 5.8, nunmpy.nan]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(plens, polyplot, linestyle='--', marker='^', markersize=7.0, color='red')
```

I have left aside the superfluous information, like the indexing of colours and labelling as they are not important to the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is remove those elements from the domain and the plotted values, like so.

I'm going to use `y` for the values that seem to maybe be in `polyplot`, and `x` for your domain, which is maybe called `plens` in the script.

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]) # Gotten from the image
y = np.array([np.nan, 4.1, 4.3, np.nan, 5.8, np.nan]) # Red circle data
y_not_nan_inds = ~np.isnan(y)

ax.plot(x[y_not_nan_inds], y[y_not_nan_inds], ...)
```

Here, we make everything into numpy arrays, find the locations where there are `y` values, and plot lines over those areas.

Comment: This sounds promising, and I forgot to show the definition, plens is just a list, [15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40], so my final data polyplot is a list of 6 values as well, just as you have specified. I'll give this a shot and see if it works out.

Comment: Sounds good. Just put the 15 into `x`, realized I only had 5 values in there.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I get a pretty weird plot, the values are all wrong, it jumps between 0 and 1, so I think it's plotting a truth table for ~np.isnan. https://imgur.com/pEInB52

Comment: Huh -- are you sure you're plotting `y[y_not_nan_inds]` and not just `y_not_nan_inds`?

Comment: Yea, that's what I did, realized after I posted hah, sorry.